# Merging Shuffled DF with new output DF - Pandas

Tags: pandas, svm

I'm trying to merge two data frames; "shuffled" DF1 that is used to derive (predicted outputs) DF2. I was able to merge them together; however, the end results are always "not shuffled" DF1 merged with DF2. Therefore, giving a mismatch to the DF3.

```
df1 = shuffle(pd.read_csv("C:/Users/.."))

filename = ('C:/Users/..')
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

df2 = loaded_model.predict(df1)

df3= pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)


Here's an example the problem.:

df1        df1 (Shuffled)     
 0         3
 1         2
 2         1
 3         0

df2
0
0
0
1

expected df3 = (shuffled df1) + df2:
df1   df2
3     0
2     0
1     0
0     1

however, im getting:
df1   df2
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1  


Thanks in advance for the time and effort!
```

Comment: by shuffled, do you mean a random shuffle? also do you just want a shuffled df1 + df2 ? for all columns? how many columns are there? can you expand the example to suit your needs

Comment: thank you for the response. I'm doing random shuffle on df1 for sanity check of a trained SVM. I've confirmed the results matches the shuffled df1. however, when i tried to merge df1 and df2, it results in a not shuffled df1 merging with df2. There are about 50 columns +-

Comment: are you sure you're using shuffled df for merging ? because the code you wrote works on the sample data

Comment: @ political scientist, yes, i printed to check that df1 is shuffled before i tried to do the merging. However, as mentioned, the end result was unshuffled df1 merging with df2. Which gives a mismatch df3